# Assign an Id to Picker Elements

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am building an Android app on Xamarin forms. I have a method that calls an API that brings next structure

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "estado": "Aguascalientes",
    "cve": null,
    "pais": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "estado": "Baja California",
    "cve": null,
    "pais": null
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "estado": "Baja California Sur",
    "cve": null,
    "pais": null
  }]
```

and I am using that json structure to display "estado" property on a picker, the problem is that I need to bind every element on that picker to id (because I use that Id for post calls). Is there a way I can store that Id on the picker in a way that when I click on an picker element I can get that id?, or what way would you recomend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deserialize your json to a `List` and assign it as the `ItemsSource`

```
List<myClass> data = // deserialize your json here
myPicker.ItemsSource = data;
// display the "Estado" property to the user
myPicker.ItemDisplayBinding = new Binding("Estado");
```

later, to retrieve the `Id` property of the selected item

```
var id = ((myClass)myPicker.SelectedItem.Id;
```